# Fecha PHP API no da resultado

Tags: php, api, date

Tengo esta llamada a una API pero no lee la fecha dando como repuesta:

Array ( [message] => "date" must be one of [string, object] [path] => date [ok] => )

Este es el código que estoy ocupando..

```
$fecha_inicial="2022-07-01T00:00:00.000Z";
$fecha_final="2022-07-31T00:00:00.000Z";

$invoices = $facturapi->Invoices->all([

 date => [
   gte => $fecha_inicial,
   lte => $fecha_final
 ],
 page => 3,
 limit => 10,
]);
```

Gracias!

Comment: A menos que alguien de la comunidad haya usado la misma API -que hasta ahora sólo tu sabes cuál es-, es mejor preguntarle a los que publican la API y te ayuden a descifrar ese mensaje tan poco descriptivo.

Comment: Que API estás usando?